# Safely viewing lists in ipython

Tags: list, jupyter-notebook

When I ask an ipython notebook to display (via evaluate) a large np.array ipython uses ellipses to summarize the data. However if I ask ipython to display a large list, no such safe guard is in place and my poor ipython notebook struggles. Are there any magics or other tools I can use? I run an ipython notebook in emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to [add display support to existing object (example with polynomial and TeX)](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb#Adding-IPython-display-support-to-existing-objects) (those you can't tamper the source with) what you are trying to define is a "pretty Formatter" (aka `_repr_pretty_`) for those. You will have a difficulty compared to numpy arrays which is that list are heterogeneous, and so the first element can be a really supper long element.

You can also look at the [plain doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html) for existing formatters, to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I'm still new to python and this functionality looks really neat.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just test the length of the list yourself? Or wrap the lists as generators?

```
>>> def guard(XS,N):
...     if len(XS) > N:
...         return "list too long" # or whatever you want
...     else:
...         return XS
... 
>>> guard([1,2,3,4],2)
'list too long'
>>> guard([1,2,3,4],6)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: Yes I can, but this solution is not particularly robust. For example, if I had a list of lists and and the first element was really long I would still have a problem. (I know I didn't really mention this concern in my original question.)